# Is there any form of local multiplayer in Halo 5?

Tags: halo-series, halo-5-guardians

The articles I've found say that Halo 5 has no local co-op and reference the story campaign.  They don't make it clear if it's just the campaign co-op that's been cut or if competitive local multiplayer has been cut as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.  This is sourced from Josh Holmes, [who has tweeted](https://twitter.com/JoshingtonState/status/615282749436358656):

> @bengvr3 @franklez @PlutonForEver @Brav All MP modes use full screen
>   on dedicated servers, incl Coop Campaign, Arena and Warzone.

Microsoft has already made clear that no split-screen or LAN play will be supported whatsoever for Halo 5, sad to say.  Sourced from [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2015/06/halo-5-listing-dev-statement-point-to-end-of-series-local-multiplayer/):

> A Microsoft spokesperson confirmed to Ars Technica that Halo 5:
>   Guardians will not support any form of split-screen multiplayer, nor
>   will the game natively support LAN play. "The decision [to remove all
>   split-screen modes] was an extremely difficult one for the team, but
>   one that was necessary to deliver the biggest Halo game to date," the
>   representative wrote in a statement. "343’s focus is to ensure that
>   fans get the best Halo experience yet, and the team felt a
>   split-screen experience would compromise the gameplay design and the
>   visual bar they’ve set."
>
> The representative pointed out that Halo: MCC was not built with LAN
>   support, as well, but we have found that LAN connectivity can be used
>   in that game so long as all connected Xbox One consoles are also
>   connected to Xbox Live via Wi-Fi.